# Parsing XML SOAP Response C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I've been struggling trying to parse with Linq (not any attachment to Linq at all, it's just the most used on the samples I found) the XML Soap Response below. I've tried some similar answers already posted on StackOverflow, but none of them deal with these multiple namespaces on different elements of the XML structure. The SOAP response is a mess, I know, but it's given. The only thing I need is the value from the *itemID* field (namely **MyITItemName**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header
    xmlns:ns="http://services.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://schemata.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/"/>
  <soapenv:Body
    xmlns:ns="http://services.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://schemata.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/">
    <ns1:createItemResponse
      xmlns:ns1="http://services.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/">
      <ns2:id
        xmlns:ns2="http://schemata.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/">338632
      </ns2:id>
      <ns2:itemID
        xmlns:ns2="http://schemata.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/">MyITItemName
      </ns2:itemID>
    </ns1:createItemResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can anyone shed a light (or some code :-) ) on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you know that you are always looking for ns2:itemID (which the MyITItemName is within), you will need to access the childnodes. I have a working example here below. I took your xml and saved it as an xml file in my downloads folder.

```
void Main()
{
    // replace this configFile location to where you save your xml file
    GetClientNoteXmlData("MyITItemName", @"C:\Users\first.last\Downloads\test.xml");
}

public void GetClientNoteXmlData(string client, string configFile)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(configFile);

    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    if (root != null)
    {
        XmlNodeList list = root.GetElementsByTagName("ns2:itemID");
        foreach (XmlNode node in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerXml);
            Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the itemId by using *Linq to XML* especially [**XDocument**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=net-5.0) :

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
  <soapenv:Header
    xmlns:ns=""http://services.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/""
    xmlns:ns1=""http://schemata.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/""/>
  <soapenv:Body
    xmlns:ns=""http://services.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/""
    xmlns:ns1=""http://schemata.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/"">
    <ns1:createItemResponse
      xmlns:ns1=""http://services.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/"">
      <ns2:id xmlns:ns2=""http://schemata.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/"">338632</ns2:id>
      <ns2:itemID xmlns:ns2=""http://schemata.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/"">MyITItemName</ns2:itemID>
   </ns1:createItemResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
```

```
XNamespace ns2 = "http://schemata.mycompany.biz/it/managementservice/ITSMIT/1/";

string itemId = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                .Descendants(ns2 + "itemID")
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .Value;
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Nelson's answer solved my problem and I accepted it. But your answer is very cool, insightful and complete indeed. Thanks a lot, @Sajid !